# CSS to pan background image back and forth

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-animations

I'm looking for a CSS-only way to animate a background image, similar to the example given here:

https://www.html5andbeyond.com/css3-animated-backgrounds-infinite-scrolling-background/

But rather than an endless loop, I want the image (a moutainscape) to slowly pan back and forth, so on pageload the viewer sees the left side of the image, and a few seconds later will see the right side, and then back again.

An important caveat is that the div with the background is full width, so setting absolute values for the animation.

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: Here is scrolling code from the example linked to above

```
<style>
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
from {background-position: 0 0;}
to {background-position: -99999999px 0;} }

@keyframes backgroundScroll {
from {background-position: 0 0;}
to {background-position: -99999999px 0;} }

#mtn-scroll {
width: 100%;
height: 35em;
background: url(mtns.jpg) no-repeat;
-webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 999999s linear infinite;
animation: backgroundScroll 999999s linear infinite; }
</style>

<div id="mtn-scroll"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please post the necessary bit of code from that article here?

Comment: Please show any attempt you have actually made at doing what you're asking and then we can help if what you've tried is causing issues.

Comment: So, animate the `background-position` then, in an infinite loop that goes from one side to the other and back …

Comment: Relevant code will help us help you.

Comment: Edited to include a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the keyframe animation to percentages.

```
@keyframes backgroundScroll {
    0%   {background-position: 0 0;}
    50%  {background-position: -400px 0;}
    100% {background-position: 0 0;}
}
```

Then just double the animation time.

```
background: url(bg-repeat.png) repeat-y;
    animation: backgroundScroll 40s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Mmmm. That almost works, except the edge of the image comes into the viewport. But with a wide enough image that could work.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Hunter Turner's answer, here is what I ended up with.

```
<style>
@keyframes backgroundScroll {
0% { background-position: 50% 50%; }
33% { background-position: 1% 50%; }
40% { background-position: 1% 50%; }
66% { background-position: 99% 50%; }
75% { background-position: 99% 50%; }
100% { background-position: 50% 50%; }}
/* added pauses to each edge of the image */

#mtn-scroll {
width: 100%;
height: 35em;
background: url(mtns.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 150%;
background-position: 50% 50%;
animation: backgroundScroll 60s ease-in-out 1s infinite; }
</style>

<div id="mtn-scroll"></div>
```